# Extra string after second underscore in file name

Tags: regex

I have a file name as follows.
tasks_6839_sr_us_3887_sr_SP_trados.wsxz

I need to create regex that just finds the two strings "sr" after the second underscore.

Can someone help please?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the two desired strings you want out of the full filename? Your explanation creates too many ambiguities

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that our desired output has a always four digits boundary on its left, then we would start with this expression:

```
_[0-9]{4}_(.+?)_
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/PKfgR1/1/)

or

```
_[0-9]{4}_([a-z]{2}?)_
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TVvj6n/1/)

and we can further simplify that, if we would like so.

In both cases, our desired output is in the capturing group `()`.

Comment: Yep I would like a Regex that capture's just the strings between the two underscores directly after the 4 digits on the left.

Comment: Also I forgot to add, thank you that seems to provide exactly what I need!